# Prove by mean value theorem, $(1 - \frac{1}{x})^x$ is an increasing function for $x > 0$.

Tags: calculus

Prove by mean value theorem, $(1 - \frac{1}{x})^x$ is an increasing function for $x > 0$.

I proved that it is increasing for $x > 1$. How to show that it is increasing when $0 < x < 1$?

Comment: What is the value of your function when $x=1/2$ ?

Comment: I think the function is not defined in $(0, 1)$.

Comment: Yes, so as you have done the work for $x>1$, you are done.